# Convert HTML to Plain Text in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm working on a simple RSS Reader app as a beginner project in Xcode. I currently have it set up that it parses the feed, and places the title, pub date, description and content and displays it in a WebView.

I recently decided to show the description (or a truncated version of the content) in the TableView used to select a post. However, when doing so:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = item.title?.uppercaseString
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = item.itemDescription //.itemDescription is a String
```

It shows the raw HTML of the post.

I would like to know how to convert the HTML into plain text for just the TableView's detailed UILabel.

Thanks!

Answer (score 252, accepted):

You can add this extension to convert your html code to a regular string:

edit/update:

> Discussion The HTML importer should not be called from a background
>   thread (that is, the options dictionary includes documentType with a
>   value of html). It will try to synchronize with the main thread, fail,
>   and time out. Calling it from the main thread works (but can still
>   time out if the HTML contains references to external resources, which
>   should be avoided at all costs). The HTML import mechanism is meant
>   for implementing something like markdown (that is, text styles,
>   colors, and so on), not for general HTML import.

**Xcode 11.4 • Swift 5.2**

```
extension Data {
    var html2AttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: self, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            print("error:", error)
            return  nil
        }
    }
    var html2String: String { html2AttributedString?.string ?? "" }
}
```

---

```
extension StringProtocol {
    var html2AttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        Data(utf8).html2AttributedString
    }
    var html2String: String {
        html2AttributedString?.string ?? ""
    }
}
```

---

```
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = item.itemDescription.html2String
```

Comment: I tried, but many HTML will return a string with some hidden stuffs in front, which can't be println, weird.

Comment: this method is very processor heavy

Comment: I'm trying to implement this extension, but I get the following error: "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'NSAttributedString' with an argument list of type '(data: NSData, options: NSDictionary, documentAttributes: _, error: _)'" Do you have any idea what I can do?

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks for the answer, I was wondering, is it possible to change the font size? The font returned is quite small and barely readable. I tried adding `NSFontAttributeName` but the output remains the same. I've asked a question here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36427442/nsfontattributename-not-applied-to-nsattributedstring

Comment: +1 for Swift 3: by default, Xcode ported my code from Swift 2 by converting `NSUTF8StringEncoding` into `String.Encoding.utf8`, but it kept crashing. Thanks to this answer, I was able to fix it by appending `.rawValue` to the `Encoding` enum.

Comment: Is there any way to apply that to all strings and it does not delete `\n`out of it?

Comment: This is fantastic, thanks! I'm having an issue with images not fitting to UILabel width even when I add `style = "max-width: 100%"` to the img tags. Text behaves appropriately, wrapping at the label's edge. Any advice? - asked question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44753628/uiscrollview-with-uilabel-text-fits-view-but-images-dont/44756163?noredirect=1#comment76536343_44756163

Comment: @LeoDabus. It doesn't work at all. Have you tested it when the html string has &amp;nbsp; at the start or end ? It just doesn't work

Comment: @zulkarnainshah `"&amp;"` returns "&" as expected and `"nbsp;"` doesn't mean anything so it returns the same thing "nbsp;". of course `"&amp;nbsp;"` will return  "&" + "nbsp;". If you would like it to return "& " you need to add the missing & `"&amp;&nbsp;"`

Comment: @LeoDabus. My HTML for example is " Hello" which starts with a space and converts to the string "@amp;nbsp;Hello". How to get only "Hello" out of that ?

Comment: @zulkarnainshah How can you get "@amp;nbsp;Hello" from  " Hello"? it doesn't make any sense. If you interpret it as html it will drop the leading space. It does return "Hello" for me here from " Hello"

Comment: @LeoDabus. I get "&amp;nbsp;Hello" NOT "@amp;nbsp;Hello"

Comment: @zulkarnainshah I don't know what are you doing there but you are probably not using the code I posted. Try creating a new playground file and add only the code I posted. If you are testing it in a real project try cleaning it.

Comment: @LeoDabus. Did that all. Still get the same result

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of your playground file containing only this extension, the original string and the result?

Comment: @LeoDabus this worked well. But, when I use it inside `cellForRow` then my tableview stucks a bit when scrolling. How to get rid of it?

Comment: doesn't compile on swift 4

Comment: This works fine on ios 10, but on ios 11 it does some weird things with the html data like it ignores the the font weight of a custom font. unless explicitly defined.

Comment: @LeoDabus I think it was some flakiness in Playgrounds. Closing Xcode and restarting resolved the error I encountered the first time.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should not execute this code from background thread. Check out Apple Docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/1524613-initwithdata

Comment: @TimurBernikowich I am not executing anything from the background thread. If you think this is important in your case  make sure to just wrap it in a `DispatchQueue.main.async { // your code }` Btw OP it is using it in a table view cellForRowAt indexPath method which is obviously run in the main thread.

Comment: I understand this, but someone can try to use it in background just like any other string func. I just left warning.

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 4, Xcode 9**

```
extension String {
    
    var utfData: Data {
        return Data(utf8)
    }
    
    var attributedHtmlString: NSAttributedString? {
        
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: utfData, options: [
              .documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
              .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
            ], 
            documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            print("Error:", error)
            return nil
        }
    }
}

extension UILabel {
   func setAttributedHtmlText(_ html: String) {
      if let attributedText = html.attributedHtmlString {
         self.attributedText = attributedText
      } 
   }
}
```

Comment: ANY string can be converted to utf8 data. Returning optional is pointless. Just `return Data(utf8)`

Comment: Here we want string to be converted in NSAttributedString, why returning just Data(utf8) would be useful?

Comment: I meant `var utf8data: Data { return Data(utf8) }` and remove the guard from your method

Comment: Btw `localizedDescription` is redundant. Just  `print(error)`

Answer (score 3):

Here is my suggested answer. Instead of extension, if you want to put inside function.

```
func decodeString(encodedString:String) -> NSAttributedString?
    {
        let encodedData = encodedString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType,NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute:NSUTF8StringEncoding], documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return nil
        }
    }
```

And call that function and cast NSAttributedString to String

```
let attributedString = self.decodeString(encodedString)
let message = attributedString.string
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift4.0 Extension

```
 extension String {
    var html2AttributedString: String? {
    guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return nil }
    do {
        return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil).string

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return  nil
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please test with this code for the detailTextLabel:

```
var attrStr = NSAttributedString(
        data: item.itemDescription.dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true),
        options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
        documentAttributes: nil,
        error: nil)
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = attrStr
```

Comment: Hi @AltimirAntonov, thanks for the reply. `item.itemDescription` is a String - perhaps I should have clarified that earlier. Should I convert it to NSData?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this solution in swift3**

```
extension String{
    func convertHtml() -> NSAttributedString{
        guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return NSAttributedString() }
        do{
            return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
        }catch{
            return NSAttributedString()
        }
    }
}
```

**To use**

```
self.lblValDesc.attributedText = str_postdescription.convertHtml()
```

Answer (score 0):

i have used Danboz answer, only changed it to return a simple String (not a rich text string):

```
static func htmlToText(encodedString:String) -> String?
{
    let encodedData = encodedString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    do
    {
        return try NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType,NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute:NSUTF8StringEncoding], documentAttributes: nil).string
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return nil
    }
}
```

for me, it works like a charm, thanks Danboz

Answer (score 0):

```
let content = givenString // html included string
let attrStr = try! NSAttributedString(data: content.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!,options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],documentAttributes: nil)
self.labelName.attributedText = attrStr
```

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 5.*

Here's a compact solution based on string extension:

```
import UIKit

extension String {
    var attributedHtmlString: NSAttributedString? {
        try? NSAttributedString(
            data: Data(utf8),
            options: [
                .documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
            ],
            documentAttributes: nil
        )
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let html = "hello <br><br/> <b>world</b>"
if let attributedText = html.attributedHtmlString {
    print(attributedText.string) // "hello \n\nworld\n"
}
```

You can also keep the attributed string ofc, based on your necessities