# NSAttributedString: Fit image to container

Tags: html, ios, image, swift, nsattributedstring

I have a NSAttributedString which is made from HTML and it displays some images. The problem is that the images are bigger than the container and I wonder how to fit them in it.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I finally found how to do that:

```
content.enumerateAttribute(NSAttachmentAttributeName, inRange: NSMakeRange(0, content.length), options: NSAttributedStringEnumerationOptions(0)) { (value, range, stop) -> Void in
    if let attachement = value as? NSTextAttachment {
        let image = attachement.imageForBounds(attachement.bounds, textContainer: NSTextContainer(), characterIndex: range.location)
        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        if image.size.width > screenSize.width-2 {
            let newImage = image.resizeImage((screenSize.width-2)/image.size.width)
            let newAttribut = NSTextAttachment()
            newAttribut.image = newImage
            content.addAttribute(NSAttachmentAttributeName, value: newAttribut, range: range)
        }
    }
}
```

The function `resizeImage()` is defined like that:

```
extension UIImage {
    func resizeImage(scale: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        let newSize = CGSizeMake(self.size.width*scale, self.size.height*scale)
        let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize)
        self.drawInRect(rect)
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return newImage
    }
}
```

### Swift 3 version

```
text.enumerateAttribute(NSAttachmentAttributeName, in: NSMakeRange(0, text.length), options: .init(rawValue: 0), using: { (value, range, stop) in
    if let attachement = value as? NSTextAttachment {
        let image = attachement.image(forBounds: attachement.bounds, textContainer: NSTextContainer(), characterIndex: range.location)!
        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
        if image.size.width > screenSize.width-20 {
            let newImage = image.resizeImage(scale: (screenSize.width-2)/image.size.width)
            let newAttribut = NSTextAttachment()
            newAttribut.image = newImage
            text.addAttribute(NSAttachmentAttributeName, value: newAttribut, range: range)
        }
    }
})
```

The function `resizeImage()` is defined like that:

```
func resizeImage(scale: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
    let newSize = CGSize(width: self.size.width*scale, height: self.size.height*scale)
    let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: newSize)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize)
    self.draw(in: rect)
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage!
}
```

### Swift 4 version + Extension and customisable max width for image

```
extension NSAttributedString {
    func attributedStringWithResizedImages(with maxWidth: CGFloat) -> NSAttributedString {
        let text = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: self)
        text.enumerateAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.attachment, in: NSMakeRange(0, text.length), options: .init(rawValue: 0), using: { (value, range, stop) in
            if let attachement = value as? NSTextAttachment {
                let image = attachement.image(forBounds: attachement.bounds, textContainer: NSTextContainer(), characterIndex: range.location)!
                if image.size.width > maxWidth {
                    let newImage = image.resizeImage(scale: maxWidth/image.size.width)
                    let newAttribut = NSTextAttachment()
                    newAttribut.image = newImage
                    text.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.attachment, value: newAttribut, range: range)
                }
            }
        })
        return text
    }
}

extension UIImage {
    func resizeImage(scale: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        let newSize = CGSize(width: self.size.width*scale, height: self.size.height*scale)
        let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: newSize)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize)
        self.draw(in: rect)
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return newImage!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 4.2**
**:** Using the approach of @Nic Hubbard

```
let htmlString = "Put Your YourHTML String Here"

let setHeightUsingCSS = "<head><style type=\"text/css\"> img{ max-height: 100%; max-width: \(self.textView.frame.size.width) !important; width: auto; height: auto;} </style> </head><body> \(htmlString) </body>"

self.textView.attributedText = setHeightUsingCSS.html2AttributedString


extension Data {
    var html2AttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: self, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            print("error:", error)
            return  nil
        }
    }
    var html2String: String {
        return html2AttributedString?.string ?? ""
    }
}

extension String {
    var html2AttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        return Data(utf8).html2AttributedString
    }
    var html2String: String {
        return html2AttributedString?.string ?? ""
    }
}
```

[extension reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28132610/5693826)

Comment: I have tried the above and the solution didn't worked, the image still goes our of the screen

Comment: @Prashanth, I updated my answer. I forgot to add `!important` and `}`. Please try again, Its working on my app.

Answer (score 4):

You can also wrap the string in a full HTML document and use `CSS` for the image sizing.

Comment: No, NSAttributesString. Give it an entire HTML document including CSS in the head tag.

Comment: Oh yeah, obviously! Thanks

Comment: @NicHubbard could you provide an example of CSS to resize image?

Comment: @Giorgio Use `img {max-width: %fpx; height: auto; text-align:center;}` and use the screen bounds to set the `max-width`.

Comment: some how max-width: 100% not worked...but other like color is worked like <style>div { color: red !important;}</style>

Comment: @HardikDarji have you found any solution for this? CSS image resizing isn't working for me too

Comment: Just use ```img {max-width: \(UIScreen.main.bounds.width)px; height: auto; text-align:center;}```to set the image to fix the device width