# Convert HTML to plain text in Swift (without using NSAttributedString)

Tags: html, ios, swift, functional-programming, foundation

I need to convert some HTML into plain text and have tried the approaches outlined here:

[Convert HTML to Plain Text in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28124119/convert-html-to-plain-text-in-swift)

The problem is that on iOS 8.2, NSAttributedString has a bug which can result in a EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash (deep inside WebKit) when HTML is rendered to plain text on a background thread. The conversion needs to be done on a background thread because it can (and usually does) take a while.

So I need a more primitive solution in Swift, ideally an idiomatic one.

It also strikes me that this is probably one of those problems which has an elegant and neat functional solution - it's essentially a `filter()` operation on a String surely?

Comment: You could try using UIWebView to load the HTML and the use `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` with a simple JS script that returns the text.

Comment: Have you tried using HTMLReader?

Answer (score 2):

somewhat late to the party, but thought it would benefit other visitors...

basically I have taken the solution from [here](https://www.developerfeed.com/how-remove-html-tags-string-ios/) and transformed it into Swift 3 syntax.

Solution uses Scanner (previously NSScanner) to find occurences of "<" then scans into the ">" taking everything in between into consideration, saving it into an NSString variable. 
Then just use `replacingOccurrences(of:with:)` passing in the NSString variable

Here's what the final function looks like:

```
private func stripHTML(fromString rawString: String) -> String {
    let scanner: Scanner = Scanner(string: rawString)
    var text: NSString? = ""
    var convertedString = rawString
    while !scanner.isAtEnd {
        scanner.scanUpTo("<", into: nil)
        scanner.scanUpTo(">", into: &text)
        convertedString = convertedString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\(text!)>", with: "")
    }

    return convertedString
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I have come up with is a regex within a String extension, which is adequate for dealing with the HTML fragments I need to deal with:

```
extension String {
    func plainTextFromHTML() -> String? {

        let regexPattern = "<.*?>"
        var err: NSError?

        if let stripHTMLRegex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: regexPattern, options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive, error: &err) {

            let plainText = stripHTMLRegex.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(self, options: NSMatchingOptions.ReportProgress, range: NSMakeRange(0, count(self)), withTemplate: "")

            return err == nil ? plainText : nil
        } else {
            println("Warning: failed to create regular expression from pattern: \(regexPattern)")
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

**Swift 2.2**

```
extension String {
    func plainTextFromHTML() -> String? {
        let regexPattern = "<.*?>"
        do {
            let stripHTMLRegex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regexPattern, options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive)
            let plainText = stripHTMLRegex.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(self, options: NSMatchingOptions.ReportProgress, range: NSMakeRange(0, self.characters.count), withTemplate: "")
            return plainText
        } catch {
            print("Warning: failed to create regular expression from pattern: \(regexPattern)")
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

A more advanced solution will be needed for full HTML conversion to plain text however.