# Swift HTML to String (keeping new lines)

Tags: html, ios, swift

I'm getting a web service response which contains strings like yesterday"&rsquo";s (without the quotes) and it also contains line jumps (\n). I've used ([Convert HTML to Plain Text in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28124119/convert-html-to-plain-text-in-swift)) to get the plain string but I loose the line jumps.  Is there a way to decode that string and keep the line jumps?

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/a/30141700/1187415 ?

Comment: Yeah, had to add "&rsquo;"   : "'", to XML predefined entities. So I'll guess I'll add more when they appear.

Comment: I was too lazy to add all the > 250 HTML entities :)