# Populating cell label with attributed string from HTML with custom CSS classes

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

Any one knows how to do this?
Having a custom cell, The sub label is a HTML snippet, with custom css classes that needs to be there to colour the text in specific places.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SearchResCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SearchResCell

    if self.searchStore != nil && self.searchStore.searchResult.count > 0 && self.searchStore.searchResult[0].searchResults.count > 0 {
        let searchRes = searchStore.searchResult[0].searchResults[indexPath.row]

        cell.titleLabel.text = searchRes.displayTitle
        cell.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()

        let attrResult = try! NSAttributedString(
            data: searchRes.wordsClean.dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
            options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
            documentAttributes: nil)
        cell.subtitleLabel.attributedText = attrResult
        cell.subtitleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right

    }

    return cell
}
```

in the attrResult there is html with css class (lets say  ABC  ). Is there a way in the attributed string to say that is Foo class? or is there any other way except from using regex or string manipulation on every string that i get form the API? it can be hundreds and it is not my API so i can't change the HTML tags in it.

HTML Text Example:

```html
bla bla bla <span class="HightlightTextClass"> highlighted text </span> more bla bra bra text
```

"

10x

Comment: Can you post the HTML?

Comment: Try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/28132610/5222077 (I'm not 100% sure it supports cutom css, it might support inline css)

Comment: Added a string example for the type os text i am getting from the API, the class in the span is for highlighting the text for that span and i need to highlight the same text... 10x

Comment: I'm not very familiar with CSS, but: Are your classes present in the HTML snippet you got from server? I mean, there declaration and properties? If not, why not redefined them each time and add it at the beginning of the html string?

Comment: Hi @Larme, I soled the problem, look at my answer at the bottom... The API response is a HTML string, and HTML can have design inside it, it can be STYLE or CLASS, the problem is when you develop a website you have a css file attached to the project and the styles are in that file, when we develop in native we don't have that file, so i just changed every class in the HTML string to style with the right style and that is working great. Hoped that help you

Answer (score 1):

You could try to insert a custom `style` tag using `regex` or similar, or you could adjust the font, color, background color, etc. by actually using the document attributes of the attributed string.

Comment: so there no way to control the class in a NSHTMLTextDocumentType ?

Comment: 10x, I've posted the solution, based on your suggestions so i gave you point

Answer (score 0):

If any one interested this is full solution for this issue, worked like a charm for me:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SearchResCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SearchResCell

    if self.searchStore != nil && self.searchStore.searchResult.count > 0 && self.searchStore.searchResult[0].searchResults.count > 0 {
        let searchRes = searchStore.searchResult[0].searchResults[indexPath.row]

        cell.titleLabel.text = searchRes.displayTitle
        cell.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()

        if let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "class=\"hlt\"", options: .CaseInsensitive) {
            let modStr = regex.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(searchRes.wordsClean, options: .WithTransparentBounds, range: NSMakeRange(0, searchRes.wordsClean.characters.count), withTemplate: "style=\"background-color:#F7DB6A\"")

            let attrResult = try! NSAttributedString(
                data: modStr.dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
                options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
                documentAttributes: nil)

            cell.subtitleLabel.attributedText = attrResult
            cell.subtitleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right

        }
    }

    return cell
}
```