# Cannot convert value of type NSAttributedString.DocumentAttributeKey to .DocumentReadingOptionKey

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, nsattributedstringkey

I found this string extension somewhere on SO that allows me to turn html code into an attributed string:

```
func html2AttributedString() -> NSAttributedString {
    return try! NSAttributedString(data: self.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
}
```

It worked fine in Swift 3, but with Swift 4, Xcode complains:

> Cannot convert value of type 'NSAttributedString.DocumentAttributeKey' to expected dictionary key type 'NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey'

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You need to pass one of the available NSAttributedString [DocumentType](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nsattributedstring.documenttype) options:

---

> Hypertext Markup Language (HTML) document.

```
static let html: NSAttributedString.DocumentType
```

---

> Plain text document.

```
static let plain: NSAttributedString.DocumentType
```

---

> Rich text format document.

```
static let rtf: NSAttributedString.DocumentType
```

---

> Rich text format with attachments document.

```
static let rtfd: NSAttributedString.DocumentType
```

---

In this case you will need to pass the first one (html)  `NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html`

So the extension [updated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28124119/2303865) to Swift 4 should look like this:

```
extension NSAttributedString {
    convenience init(data: Data, documentType: DocumentType, encoding: String.Encoding = .utf8) throws {
        try self.init(data: data,
                      options: [.documentType: documentType,
                                .characterEncoding: encoding.rawValue],
                      documentAttributes: nil)
    }
    convenience init(html data: Data) throws {
        try self.init(data: data, documentType: .html)
    }
    convenience init(txt data: Data) throws {
        try self.init(data: data, documentType: .plain)
    }
    convenience init(rtf data: Data) throws {
        try self.init(data: data, documentType: .rtf)
    }
    convenience init(rtfd data: Data) throws {
        try self.init(data: data, documentType: .rtfd)
    }
}
```

---

```
extension StringProtocol {
    var data: Data { return Data(utf8) }
    var htmlToAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        do {
            return try .init(html: data)
        } catch {
            print("html error:", error)
            return nil
        }
    }
    var htmlDataToString: String? {
        return htmlToAttributedString?.string
    }
}
```

---

```
extension Data {
    var htmlToAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        do {
            return try .init(html: self)
        } catch {
            print("html error:", error)
            return nil
        }

    }
}
```

---

Playground Testing

```
let htmlString = "<style type=\"text/css\">#red{color:#F00}#green{color:#0F0}#blue{color: #00F; font-weight: Bold; font-size: 32}</style><span id=\"red\" >Red</span><span id=\"green\" > Green </span><span id=\"blue\">Blue</span>"

let htmlData = Data(htmlString.utf8)

htmlString.htmlToAttributedString
htmlData.htmlToAttributedString
```

> Discussion The HTML importer should not be called from a background
>   thread (that is, the options dictionary includes documentType with a
>   value of html). It will try to synchronize with the main thread, fail,
>   and time out. Calling it from the main thread works (but can still
>   time out if the HTML contains references to external resources, which
>   should be avoided at all costs). The HTML import mechanism is meant
>   for implementing something like markdown (that is, text styles,
>   colors, and so on), not for general HTML import

Comment: This is fantastic. I was able to convert `&#36` in an API to $. It's incredibly verbose though. Is there a more Swifty way? Thanks.

Comment: Tried it out. It's a wash because it's only eliminating three error lines `catch, print, return` but then you have to use `String(describing:` on your property anyway. Plus I should error check when using an API. Maybe Swift 5 will let us do it in one magic method like `encodeHTML` =P.

Comment: Yes. Functionality is same. I was trying to say that removing `catch`, `print`, and `return` is insignificant considering the tradeoff in safety.   They all work. Very scary though :)

Comment: If I'm getting a zombie about 25% of the time I invoke this, what would you say I'm doing wrong? I'm not explicitly deallocating anywhere

Comment: Can't we add HTML table ? ex.`let htmlTable = "<table> <tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Favorite Color</th> </tr> <tr> <td>Bob</td> <td>Yellow</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Michelle</td> <td>Purple</td> </tr> </table>"`

Comment: @LeoDabus i have shifted my code into `WebKit` which provide rich html features

Answer (score 23):

Had this after automatic conversion to Swift 4. Was fixed by changing from:

```
NSMutableAttributedString(data: data, 
   options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentAttributeKey.documentType : NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], 
   documentAttributes: nil)
```

to:

```
NSMutableAttributedString(data: data,
   options: [.documentType : NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html],
   documentAttributes: nil) {
```

Comment: this is solution. thk a lot

Answer (score 14):

This works for me:

```
let attrStr = try! NSAttributedString(
    data: modifiedFont.data(using: .unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
    options:[.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
    .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
    documentAttributes: nil)
```

If you don’t add

> .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.**rawValue**

the app will crash.

Comment: How can I give fontSize & font in it?

Answer (score 7):

**swift 4** : I dont know why all the answers have compiler error for me. so  use this extension:

```
extension String {
    var html2AttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: data(using: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))!,
                                          options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                                                    .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
                                          documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            print("error: ", error)
            return nil
        }
    }
    var html2String: String {
        return html2AttributedString?.string ?? ""
    }
}
```

how to use ?

mylable.text = htmlVariable.html2String

Answer (score 4):

For HTML string, `NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html` is the correct option.

#### Swift 4

```
extension String {

    var utfData: Data? {
        return self.data(using: .utf8)
    }

    var htmlAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        guard let data = self.utfData else {
            return nil
        }
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: data,
           options: [
                     NSAttributedString.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                     NSAttributedString.characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
                    ], documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html`

```
NSMutableAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html] , documentAttributes: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use NSAttributedStringKey and had similar error "Cannot convert value of type" on Swift 4. In case anyone using NSAttributedStringKey comes here looking for an answer, this is how I fixed:

```
let TextStroke: [NSAttributedStringKey : Any] = [
    NSAttributedStringKey(rawValue: NSAttributedStringKey.strokeColor.rawValue) : UIColor.black,
    NSAttributedStringKey(rawValue: NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue) : UIColor.white,
    NSAttributedStringKey(rawValue: NSAttributedStringKey.strokeWidth.rawValue) : -6.0,]
```

And this is how I add the attribute to the text:

```
myLabel.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: myString, attributes: TextStroke)
```

Comment: This is horribly cumbersome. The benefit of `NSAttributedStringKey` is to avoid those long-winded initializations. You should simply write `let textStroke: [NSAttributedStringKey : Any] = [.strokeColor : UIColor.black, .foregroundColor : UIColor.white, .strokeWidth : -6.0]
`

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.x** & **5.x**

```
if let rtfPath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "FileName", withExtension: "rtf") {
        do {
            let attributedString: NSAttributedString = try NSAttributedString(url: rtfPath, options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.rtf], documentAttributes: nil)
            debugPrint(attributedString)
        } catch {
            print("Error while reading the file - \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
 }
```

Getting NSAttributedString from file will be changed in **Swift 3.x** which is as below:

```
let attributedStringWithRtf: NSAttributedString = try NSAttributedString(url: rtfPath, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSRTFTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
```

all the other code same as **Swift 4.x** & **5.x**.

For more details please read the Apple document related to the [NSAttributedStringDocumentType](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nsattributedstringdocumenttype?language=objc)