# DocumentReadingOptionKey key corrupt after swift4 migration

Tags: swift4, xcode9

Using the following code migrated from swift3 to swift4,

```
let options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey: AnyHashable] =
                          [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue]

            let str = try NSAttributedString( data:string!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true
                )!, options:options, documentAttributes: nil)
```

iOS 9+ has no problem, when running iOS 8.3, console output: "dyld: Symbol not found: _NSCharacterEncodingDocumentOption"; It would be passed after commented ".characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue".

Comment: Change your options dictionary value type declaration from AnyHashable to Any. `[NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey : Any]`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44391644/2303865

Comment: Btw your NSAttributedString initializer signature it is incorrect also

Comment: @LeoDabus, it can pass compiler, and works good for iOS 9+. What is an another possible right signature to using for HTML for encodingCode?

Comment: `NSAttributedString(data:,
                                          options:,
                                          documentAttributes:)`

Comment: I have same problem. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution. You should to remove .characterEncoding for swift4.
It works on ios8,9,11.

Example:

```
public func htmlToString() -> String? {
        guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return nil }
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(
                data: data,
                options: [
                    .documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html
                ],
                documentAttributes: nil
            ).string
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return  nil
        }
    }
```

Have a good day!

Comment: Thanks @nullrpoduction. It doesn‘t work on iOS 10? YES,  remove .characterEncoding can works. Course default encoding is UTF-8, so it works. But if not encoded utf-8, how to do?

Comment: For example, my project using the following code [unicode encoding]:                                      
  try NSAttributedString( data: string.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
                                              options:[.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil )

Comment: Thanks, my app was working fine above iOS 8 and for iOS 8, the problem turned out to be what you said. Saved me a lot.

Comment: @kubilay For iOS 8, use this way would work `NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey(rawValue: "CharacterEncoding")`

Answer (score 1):

For all iOS 8, use this way for the key

`NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey(rawValue: "CharacterEncoding")`

instead of putting

`NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.characterEncoding`

directly.

Note: Don't use version check to call `NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.characterEncoding`, otherwise, it still doesn't work.