# UIScrollView with UILabel - text fits view but images don't

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uilabel

I have a scroll view with a text label pinned to it. The text label contains html attributed text (converted by [using the accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28124119/convert-html-to-plain-text-in-swift)) which includes images such as graphs. I'm able to get the text to fit on screen, but the images are being cut off on the trailing side

Edit: The image is being pulled in like so:

`<p><img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/ZhaF0f-JiPOmvvFS4qor‌ -gVpqFALuXcbwM8bBHIB‌ 0I9dFRoUZkxQUx5G-0Cb‌ PcuRNnC2Zw0Ty3lp9Ykr‌ 3X00Iy0RfiLVJnsLP9Fu‌ C_wORRhixVd3fm5JA27I‌ MUTkFPf1JkZvLBFW" style="border:none; height:324px; width:624px" /></p>`

Edit: The Scroll View's width is fixed because I'm only wanting it to scroll vertically

Edit: Constraints are set in storyboard if that matters[image]

Comment: try adding `label.setNeedsLayout()` and `label.layoutIfNeeded()` after setting the value

Comment: Also, try removing the <p> tags from the html and see if that works

Comment: it happening because image being displayed here takes it original size you just need to give a defined size to image so it don't cross the view on trailing or leading side. Set a frame that have parameter of width as self.view.frame.size.width

Comment: Thanks both of you.

@Malik - I tried setNeedsLayout and layoutIfNeeded after setting the value and the image still bleeds off

@ iOS Geek - Do you mean setting the label's frame to the view's width? Like `label.frame.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width`? If so, this had no effect

Comment: @froggomad Have you tried removing the <p> tags from the html?

Comment: trying to, not used to working with Attributed strings

Comment: removed <p> tags - no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is the image takes its original size.

You should set the max width of the image in the html, like so :

```
<img style="max-width: 100%;" src="mysrc.jpg" />
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm pulling this from an API I don't control

Comment: Parse the data you retrieve then, add the attribute style to every <img/>.

Comment: Thanks for that. `let politImage = self.Request.article.replacingOccurrences(of: "<img ", with: "<img style=\"max-width: 100%; \"")
      print(self.Request.article)
      //change html to htmlAttributedString
      if let htmlArticle = politImage.html2AttributedString {
        self.articleLbl.attributedText = htmlArticle`
Isn't changing the <img tags

Comment: lol I just realized I'm printing the wrong thing - the tag is changed but the result is the same. I'm about 18 years past having done any serious html work though so I'm not sure `<img style="max-width: 100%; "src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/ZhaF0f-JiPOmvvFS4qor-gVpqFALuXcbwM8bBHIB0I9dFRoUZkxQUx5G-0CbPcuRNnC2Zw0Ty3lp9Ykr3X00Iy0RfiLVJnsLP9FuC_wORRhixVd3fm5JA27IMUTkFPf1JkZvLBFW" style="border:none; height:324px; width:624px" /></p>` produces what you're after

Comment: oops - I reformatted that to `<img style="max-width: 100%;" src=blah` but Images are still cut off - I just caught the hard coded width in there at the end. I'll try to handle that

Comment: I've got that to `<img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/ZhaF0f-JiPOmvvFS4qor-gVpqFALuXcbwM8bBHIB0I9dFRoUZkxQUx5G-0CbPcuRNnC2Zw0Ty3lp9Ykr3X00Iy0RfiLVJnsLP9FuC_wORRhixVd3fm5JA27IMUTkFPf1JkZvLBFW" style="max-width: 100%;" /></p>` - but no change

Comment: I just realized I'm also using a different result from yesterday since the top story changed and the image is being pulled in a different way from the example in my question. Sorry for any confusion there

Comment: 6 months later I realized I fubared as usual lol

"\"max-width: \(self.view.frame.width)px\"" was what I needed there, your answer of max-width being the key