# Convert utf-8 text to UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, utf-8, uilabel

I'm trying to download the text in **utf-8** format from the JSON file stored in the server, which then would be used as the text in the `UILabel`.

Right now, I don't know what code I should include in the text so that the targeted wordings

1) could be bold

2) whose font size could be changed to, say 18, from the default 15 in the `UILabel`

**For Example:**

`< b>Topic< /b>` (no space inside <> in practice, just try to avoid the formatting issue here..). 
Just like, if I want to open a new line after a sentence, I could do the following:

"**This is the first sentence\r\nThis is the second sentence**",

it would appear as the below in the `UILabel`

**Output:**

```
This is the first sentence

This is the second sentence
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can u be more elaborate the question .

Comment: Please explain it more.

Comment: I mean what kind of codes I should include in the string text in my JSON file so that the UILabel could show the intended format, say the text "hello" could be displayed as bold "<b>hello</b>". Thanks!

Comment: @Howard Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are doing is know as Attributed string or you can say formated string.

As you are using HTML entity in the string and you want these HTML entity will reflect according to its tag then you have to do folloeing :

1. Convert HTML to Atrributed String.
2. Assign attributed string to `label`.

**Code**

1. Convert Simple string to attributed string.

   ```
    extension String{
    func convertHtml() -> NSAttributedString{
       guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return NSAttributedString() }
       do{
           return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
       }catch{
           return NSAttributedString()
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. Assign it as attributed text.

   ```
   self.lblAtt.attributedText = STRHTML2.convertHtml()
   ```

**Example**

Test String : `"hello, <b>john</b>"`

Output :

[image]

Comment: This looks like a copy from https://stackoverflow.com/a/47438036/1187415, without attribution.

Comment: @MartinR Im not awared about that post, yeah they are same, but I copied this text from my project which is started many mnths before n I m dealing like this.

Comment: Works fine - didn‘t even know one could use HTML tags in Swift. Have to update many labels now :D