# Cannot convert value of type 'NSAttributedString.DocumentAttributeKey'

Tags: nsattributedstring

I have used the following code multiple times in the past and in one application it still compiles just fine:

```
let attrStr = try! NSAttributedString(data: myLabel.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode,allowLossyConversion: true)!, options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
```

Now, I've started a new app and I get the following error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'NSAttributedString.DocumentAttributeKey' to expected dictionary key type 'NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey'
```

Can't seem to find anything that is applicable to fixing this, has something changed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert HTML to Plain Text in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28124119/convert-html-to-plain-text-in-swift)

Comment: There is a change in Swift 4 and NSAttributedString in general (keys, values, etc.)

Comment: Then why doesn't the old code blow up?

Comment: I guess it's because you were still using Swift 3 in the previous app, but on the new one, you are using Swift 4 (default value for new projects)?