# Swift - Convert HTML text to Attributed String

Tags: html, ios, swift, nsattributedstring

In one of my module, I want show the multiple language HTML texts (English and Tamil) as a NSAttributedString using UILabel. If the text would be pure english, I can show it as my desire [Using this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28124119/convert-html-to-plain-text-in-swift?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). But my content has contain both English and Tamil characters. How could I handle this scenario. Kindly share your suggestions, If anyone know about that.

> HTML Content

```
<medium><b><font color='#2f3744'>IPL Tamil Web Series Episode #3 | யாருடா Swetha ? | Tamil Comedy Web Series | Being Thamizhan</font></b></medium> has been succesfully scheduled on <medium><b><font color='#2f3744'>2018-05-23 08:51 PM</font></b></medium>
```

> Expectation

**IPL Tamil Web Series Episode #3 | யாருடா Swetha ? | Tamil Comedy Web Series | Being Thamizhan** has been succesfully scheduled on **2018-05-23 08:45 PM**

> Current Output

**IPL Tamil Web Series Episode #3 | &*$%!@#$@^&$&^%$ Swetha ? | Tamil Comedy Web Series | Being Thamizhan** has been succesfully scheduled on **2018-05-23 08:45 PM**

Note: I tried with below code snippet to archive this

```
extension String {
var htmlToAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
    guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return NSAttributedString() }
    do {
        return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options:
            [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil)
    } catch {
        return NSAttributedString()
    }
}
var htmlToString: String {
    return htmlToAttributedString?.string ?? ""
}
}
```

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: Sure bro. I have updated my question with the code.

Comment: May this lib will help you: https://github.com/CrossWaterBridge/Attributed

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I tried this solution with your html and worked fine:

```
let htmlText = "<medium><b><font color='#2f3744'>IPL Tamil Web Series Episode #3 | யாருடா Swetha ? | Tamil Comedy Web Series | Being Thamizhan</font></b></medium> has been succesfully scheduled on <medium><b><font color='#2f3744'>2018-05-23 08:51 PM</font></b></medium>"
let encodedData = htmlText.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
var attributedString: NSAttributedString

do {
    attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType:NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.characterEncoding:NSNumber(value: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)], documentAttributes: nil)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
} catch {
    print("error")
}
```

`attributedString` output:

**IPL Tamil Web Series Episode #3 | யாருடா Swetha ? | Tamil Comedy Web Series | Being Thamizhan** has been succesfully scheduled on **2018-05-23 08:45 PM**

Comment: image loading issue

Comment: bold tag doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

```
var htmlAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: Data(utf8), options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            print("error:", error)
            return nil
        }
    }
    var htmlString: String {
        return htmlAttributedString?.string ?? ""
    }
```

> Using this you can get the string itself instead of attributed string.
> Please make sure you are using the main thread else it might crash.

Comment: Perfect. But I wonder, why <b> doesnt work?