# ios swift index 0 beyond bounds for empty array when calculate height in collectionview

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

i want calculate height of collection view cell on HTML string. HTML string converted to string by bottom extension. but when runtime this error and crash:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

my code:

```
extension String {
    var htmlToAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return NSAttributedString() }
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            return NSAttributedString()
        }
    }
    var htmlToString: String {
        return htmlToAttributedString?.string ?? ""
    }
}
```

in method `cellForItemAt`:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    //let cell  = ....
    cell?.biographyTextView.text = artistModel?.biography?.htmlToString
}
```

and in method `sizeForItemAt`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let htmlToString = artistModel?.biography?.htmlToString
    let size = CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
    let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)]
    let estimatedFrame = NSString(string: htmlToString!).boundingRect(with: size, options: [.usesFontLeading, .usesLineFragmentOrigin], attributes: attributes, context: nil)
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: estimatedFrame.height)
}
```

biography text is for example:

```
<p>blahblah><br /><br/><li>asd</li>....
```

Comment: Which line exactly is causing the error?

Comment: And you really need to write safer optional handling.

Comment: @rmaddy when i use `NSString(string: artistModel?.biography!)` it fixed. but with htmlToString extension has error.

Comment: Again, which line exactly is causing the error?

Comment: @rmaddy idk. perhaps this line `let htmlToString = artistModel?.biography?.htmlToString` in `sizeForItemAt` method

Comment: You need to know without guessing. Use the debugger. Where does it crash?

Comment: @rmaddy this line `let estimatedFrame = NSString(string: htmlToString!).boundingRect(with: size, options: [.usesFontLeading, .usesLineFragmentOrigin], attributes: attributes, context: nil)` with this error: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'`

Comment: Your catch block should not return a new object it should return nil

Comment: Btw whats the purpose of using a do try catch error handling syntax in your extension if you are ignoring the error

Comment: @LeoDabus i tested `return nil` but with same error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28132610/2303865

Comment: You need to break your code down to be able to spot which array is empty

Comment: @LeoDabus what is means `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT` ?

Comment: @LeoDabus how to use my code with main thread? (biography text is too long string)

Comment: @LeoDabus fixed. thanks bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. according answer by **@Leo Dabus**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28132610/2303865

problem fixed on Main Thread. before using extenstion convert html to string in `sizeForItemAt`. it must convert on main thread. thanks all

Answer (score 1):

Clean this up. Change:

```
let htmlToString = artistModel?.biography?.htmlToString
```

to:

```
guard let artist = artistModel, let biblio = artist.biography else {return a default size}

let htmlToString = biblio.htmlToString
```

Comment: `artistModel` and `biography` prepared and exists. not nulled