# iOS/Swift4: How to convert a .sql file into the good format utf8 in a String without bad characters even if it contains some encrypted AES fields?

Tags: ios, swift, encoding, utf-8, aes

I have a dumpfilename.sql that I want to import into a swift String for a queries execution. My problem is the utf8 encoding that is not working.

Here is the function I use:

```
 if let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "dumpfilename", ofType: "sql") {
        do {
            str = try String(contentsOfFile: filepath, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii) //String.Encoding.utf8
            str = String(utf8String:str)!
            str = self.removeSubStringIn(mainStr: str, fromStr: "/\\*", toStr: "\\*/", includingFromAndTo: true)!
        } catch {
            // contents could not be loaded
        }
    } else {
        // example.txt not found!
    }
```

Here is an extract that is not working in the .sql file (bad √© and Ã© appearing)

```
INSERT INTO `Table_CNIType` VALUES (2,0,'Carte d\'identit√©','CI','','','',1);
INSERT INTO `Table_CNIType` VALUES (2,0,\'Carte d\\\'identitÃ©\',\'CI\',\'\',\'\',\'\',1);
```

I tried to use `String(contentsOfFile: filepath, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)` that is not working. It makes me an empty string.

only `String.Encoding.ascii` & `String.Encoding.macOSRoman` is working

in terminal, the command file -I gives=> `dumpfilename.sql:  text/html; charset=utf-8`

**EDIT 1:**
May be it should be `text/plain; charset=utf-8`?
Here is the [file](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/ffc816a85997eebe6724946a2d48339720190206174157/1c9a96) example

The file is generated with the mysqldump command with the parameters: `'--compact', '--skip-set-charset', '--skip-opt', '--default-character-set=utf8'`

The swift error message is: `Code=261 "The file “dumpfilename.sql” couldn’t be opened using text encoding Unicode (UTF-8)."`

**EDIT 2:**
The error is because there is some AES encrypted data in it like this  `#õgñÚCódñ^J¥]˚m%r9†U*3j–xR+“páπ§`, so it shows me the `√©` instead of the `é` for example.

Comment: What is the String encoding of your sql file?

Comment: You need to use the actual encoding used by the file.

Comment: @LeoDabus the string encoding is text/plain; charset=utf-8 (using the file file -I command on the mac)

Comment: Are you sure? It wouldn't return nil. try utf16

Comment: @LeoDabus it makes me japanese character "⼪ℴ〱〱⁓䕔⁀獡癥摟捳彣汩敮琠††㴠䁀捨慲慣瑥牟獥瑟捬楥湴‪⼻ਯ⨡㐰㄰ㄠ卅吠捨慲慣瑥牟獥瑟捬..."

Comment: `String(utf8String:)` where is it declared? Whats the purpose of it? Seems to me that your sql file it is probably `.ascii` encoded. Note that all swift strings are utf8 encoded by default. `String(contentsOfFile: filepath, encoding: .ascii)` should be enough.

Comment: If you need to encode your swift string as .utf8 is simple just pass your string UTF8View to a data initialiser  `Data(str.utf8)`

Comment: @LeoDabus When I open it with *TextWrangler*, it is not the good characters, but if I open it with *Sublime Text* the characters are good

Comment: Have you tried with a different sql file? Seems to me that your file is not properly encoded.

Comment: Have you tried `isoLatin1` string encoding? `let str = String(contentsOfFile: filepath, encoding: .isoLatin1)`

Comment: @LeoDabus It does the same. I made a mistake, the file -I is giving *text/html; charset=utf-8* and not *text/plain; charset=utf-8*. Is there something on that side?

Comment: If you need to load an html file you need to use NSAttributedString initializer and pass the document type .html https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28124119/convert-html-to-plain-text-in-swift/28132610#28132610

Comment: @LeoDabus I checked the error, it is because in the file, I have some AES encrypted fields with data like this: *#õgñÚCódñ^J¥]˚m%r9†U*3j–xR+“páπ§* . If I remove them, it works. I have to find a solution to that. Thanks for your help