# How to convert html to string

Tags: html, swift

In order to convert html to string, I use this [extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28132610/2303865):

```
extension Data {
    var html2AttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: self, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            print("error:", error)
            return  nil
        }
    }
    var html2String: String {
        return html2AttributedString?.string ?? ""
    }
}

extension String {
    var html2AttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        return Data(utf8).html2AttributedString
    }
    var html2String: String {
        return html2AttributedString?.string ?? ""
    }
}
```

But text what i get in API i must convert with `NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html` and sometime with `NSAttributedString.DocumentType.plain`

How can i combine these two parameters?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by combining the two parameters? What is your desired output?

Comment: If the document is a plain text don't use the extension. You can check the url UTI type (if the url points to a html or a txt file)

Comment: Can you post some text samples you expect to receive from your API?

Comment: Sometime i get html text and all work fine with html parameter, but sometime i get something like this "Hello world.\n\nHello world: \n~ one \n~  two" and extension delete (\n) spaces

Answer (score 0):

What those extensions do is (1) to create a `Data` object out of an HTML string, (2) to convert the `Data` object into an `NSAtrributedString` object.  In other words, it goes like the following.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // MARK: - Variables

    // MARK: - IBOutlet
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    // MARK: - IBAction
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let htmlStr = makeHTMLString()
        let data = Data(htmlStr.utf8)
        if let attributedString = try?NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil) {
            //print(attributedString.string)
            label.attributedText = attributedString
        }
    }

    func makeHTMLString() -> String {
        return "<html>\n<head></head>\n<body>\n<h1>Hello, world!</h1>\n</body>\n</html>"
    }
}
```

In the end, you don't need those extensions.