# Swift- regex to find replace part of result

Tags: swift, regex, xcode, replace

My first question here. I have a code which is single line string which has a lot of symbols. String consists of many similar segments including date. I would like to search for a parts of string with date formatter of dd/mm/yy and insert new line \n symbol before date formatter. I think of using regex, however I am new to swift/proggraming. 
Can You advice me how to do it? thank you very much!

```
//Input string
Let configstring = "01/01/19 AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE FFF GGG HHH III JJJ KKK 0000 1111 0000 0000 1111 0000 0000 LLLL 01/02/19 MMM NNN OOO PPP RRR SSS TTT UUU 0000 1111 1111 0000 1111 1111 0000 1111 0000 0000 WWWW "
```

expected result string

```
Let configstring = "/n01/01/19 AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE FFF GGG HHH III JJJ KKK 0000 1111 0000 0000 1111 0000 0000 LLLL /n01/02/19 MMM NNN OOO PPP RRR SSS TTT UUU 0000 1111 1111 0000 1111 1111 0000 1111 0000 0000 WWWW "
```

Comment: are the dates you have in your string is always a valid date ?

Comment: I just edited date formatter. Dates are random but always with format of dd/mm/yy. I think that regex pattern should be based on those two slashes, but I don't know how to write this pattern.

Comment: You can use `(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NSDataDetector` to detect dates with any format in your string, get its NSRange, convert to `Range<String.Index>`, check if the string found on that range matches the desired date format and if it matches just insert the new line character at `range.lowerBound`:

---

```
extension Formatter {
    static let customDate: DateFormatter = {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yy"  // or "MM/dd/yy"
        return dateFormatter
    }()
}
```

---

**Playground testing:**

```
var configstring = "01/01/19 AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE FFF GGG HHH III JJJ KKK 0000 1111 0000 0000 1111 0000 0000 LLLL 01/02/19 MMM NNN OOO PPP RRR SSS TTT UUU 0000 1111 1111 0000 1111 1111 0000 1111 0000 0000 WWWW "

do {
    let ranges = try NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.date.rawValue)
            .matches(in: configstring, range: .init(configstring.startIndex..., in: configstring))
            .compactMap { Range<String.Index>($0.range, in: configstring) }
    for range in ranges.reversed() {
        // check if the date found matches the desired format
        if let date = Formatter.customDate.date(from: String(configstring[range])) {
            print("date match:", date)
            configstring.insert("\n", at: range.lowerBound)
        }
    }
} catch { 
    print(error) 
}

print(configstring)  // "\n01/01/19 AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE FFF GGG HHH III JJJ KKK 0000 1111 0000 0000 1111 0000 0000 LLLL \n01/02/19 MMM NNN OOO PPP RRR SSS TTT UUU 0000 1111 1111 0000 1111 1111 0000 1111 0000 0000 WWWW \n"
```

---

Or using regular expression

```
let pattern = "\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{2}"  // or "(\\d{2}/){2}\\d{2}" or "\\d{2}(/\\d{2}){2}"
var configstring = "01/01/19 AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE FFF GGG HHH III JJJ KKK 0000 1111 0000 0000 1111 0000 0000 LLLL 01/02/19 MMM NNN OOO PPP RRR SSS TTT UUU 0000 1111 1111 0000 1111 1111 0000 1111 0000 0000 WWWW "
var startIndex = configstring.startIndex
while let range = configstring[startIndex...].range(of: pattern, options: .regularExpression) {
    // check if the date found matches the desired format
    if let date = Formatter.customDate.date(from: String(configstring[range])) {
        print("date match:", date)
        configstring.insert("\n", at: range.lowerBound)
    }
    startIndex = range.upperBound
}

print(configstring)  // "\n01/01/19 AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE FFF GGG HHH III JJJ KKK 0000 1111 0000 0000 1111 0000 0000 LLLL \n01/02/19 MMM NNN OOO PPP RRR SSS TTT UUU 0000 1111 1111 0000 1111 1111 0000 1111 0000 0000 WWWW \n"
```

Comment: using NSDataDetector was throwing me an error, however regular expression works like a charm! thank You so much!

Comment: i have thicked green mark left of Your answer, thank You!

Comment: I do not want to start new topic, but I have another question: by using same method which was provided by Leo Dabus how to remove all spaces between last string segment and new line symbol which was added near date segment? I have this:    LLLL \n01/02/19 and I want this:    LLLL\n01/02/19.  Problem is that in my real string there are different number of spaces near each date segment.

Comment: Do you mean trim white spaces at the end of the lines?

Comment: Yes I would like to trim whitespaces at the end of the lines, however if there is a method to find all spaces between known regular expression and nearest char other than space I would prefer this one, because I will probably need such function in near future. Thank You!

Comment: `configstring = configstring.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
    .replacingOccurrences(of: "\\s+\n", with: "\n", options: .regularExpression)`

Comment: You are very helpful and fast! I will give it a try. Thank You!

Comment: you are welcome. `"\\s+\n"` will match any number of white spaces followed by a new line.

Comment: Your code of course works perfectly. My string is created by parsing data from html file. I noticed that I have rows of consecutive &nbsp; non breaking spaces which is causing a lot of problems in my code. Another question raises how to using same principle as in previous question detect consecutive arrays of &nbsp;'s and replace them by only one whitespace (" ")? those arrays of &nbsp; consists of different number of consecutive &nbsp:'s, sometimes one, sometimes six. Thanks

Comment: Better to parse your html using NSAttributedString

Comment: i am actually using NSAttributedString.. I found regex calculator and got to answer of (?:&nbsp;+){2,} for two or more &nbsp;'s which is very good!

Comment: use this extension https://stackoverflow.com/a/28132610/2303865 so you can do `"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".html2String` which  will return `"    "`

Comment: and for replacing multiple spaces for a single space `.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\s{2,}", with: " ", options: .regularExpression)`

Comment: Leo- You are very perceptive. You right, I was about to use NSAttributed string, I made extension according to link that You just shared, but finally I was not able to figure out how to call this function, so I ended up with removing html headers from html to text converted string. So let's make it work now. If my html data is stored as let htmldataflight how I should change call 'cell.detailTextLabel?.text = item.itemDescription.html2String' to work with my code? thanks...