# NSAttributedString from UTF16 characters in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I have the following code to make a hyperlink for a string within a `UITextView`

```swift
extension UITextView {
  func setAttributed(text: String) {
    self.attributedText = text.htmlAttributedString()
  }
}

extension String {
  func htmlAttributedString(document: NSAttributedString.DocumentType = .html) -> NSAttributedString? {
    guard let data = self.data(using: .utf16, allowLossyConversion: false), let font = font else { return nil }
    do {
      return try NSMutableAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: document, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf16.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
    } catch {
      debugger("error in string conversion. \(error.localizedDescription)")
      return nil
    }
}
```

And it is call like: `self.messageTextView.setAttributed(text: "<a href=\"\(utf16_str1)\">\(utf16_str2)</a>")`

It is working fine when the `text` contains only simple *utf8* characters and returns the following result:

```c
text {
    NSColor = "kCGColorSpaceModelRGB 0 0 0.933333 1 ";
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x1056bd910> font-family: \"Times New Roman\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 12.00pt";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSLink = "https://google.com";
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 15/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (\n), Lists (\n), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation NO, HeaderLevel 0 LineBreakStrategy 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "kCGColorSpaceModelRGB 0 0 0.933333 1 ";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
    NSUnderline = 1;
}
```

However, when `text` contains *utf16* characters such as *ä* or *ö*, the result is broken as below:

```c
<a href="https://google.com">textäö</a>{
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x109f0eb30> font-family: \".SFUI-Regular\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 12.00pt";
}
```

**How can I fix the issue so strings with chars like *ä* don't break the result**

Comment: You should use utf8 when converting your string to data.  It will never fail. 
`NSMutableAttributedString(data: Data(utf8),...` https://stackoverflow.com/a/28132610/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus using `utf8` results in weird characters instead of original ones. `utf16` works fine when it is used on `UILabel`

Comment: Are you using this to make asynchronous requests?

Comment: @LeoDabus No, it is used to show texts in Finnish on different pages. Contents are gotten from a server.

Comment: Show how you are getting your contents, what is the data returned and how you are setting your attributed text

Comment: @LeoDabus I already mentioned how the function is called. `url` and `name` are simply _utf16_ strings

Comment: You need to show how you are creating g utf16_str1 and utf16_str2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, strings with non-ascii characters have to be normalized before such use cases. The issue is resolved using `precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping` as documented here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1412645-precomposedstringwithcanonicalma.