# Display formatted html in UILabel using Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

I read several posts and all suggested using the following extension, but it's not working:

```
extension String {
    func htmlAttributedString() -> NSAttributedString? {
        guard let data = self.data(using: .utf8) else {
            return nil
        }

        return try? NSAttributedString(
            data: data,
            options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html],
            documentAttributes: nil
        )
    }
}
```

This is how I use it:

[image]

At runtime I get this error:

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Is that on Playground? If not, is there an error message in console when it crashes? Is it call in background?

Comment: Make sure to use it on the main thread. Note that you should not use it to display content downloaded asynchronously. **Discussion The HTML importer should not be called from a background thread (that is, the options dictionary includes documentType with a value of html). It will try to synchronize with the main thread, fail, and time out. Calling it from the main thread works (but can still time out if the HTML contains references to external resources, which should be avoided at all costs).**

Comment: **The HTML import mechanism is meant for implementing something like markdown (that is, text styles, colors, and so on), not for general HTML import.**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28132610/2303865

Comment: Btw don't you have a better name for your property?

Comment: @LeoDabus This is called inside tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath). The data is retrieved from the API and then I reloadData():

                // Reload tableview
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.setupView()
                    self.eventTableView.reloadData()
                }

Comment: @LeoDabus I agree about the property name. This was just a copy paste from an example I was trying. The example uses hard coded html. When i get it working I'll use my property.